# Complex mySQL query with joint and custom fields

Tags: mysql

I need to find a way to "concatenate" two fields (something like key=>value).
For example in that query i want to only show Items where (fielddef_id = 4 => fieldval.value = "Documents téléchargeables") AND (fielddef_id = 5 => fieldval.value = "Anglais").

Table fielddef stores the key
Table fieldvalue stores the value

But there are many combinations : key = value ... (eg : lang = English, type = downolad)

```
SELECT item.item_id AS id, item.title AS title, item.active AS active, item_cat.category_id AS cat_id, item_cat.item_id AS item_id, category.category_id, category.category_name as cat_name, category.category_alias as cat_alias 
FROM `cms_module_listit2ressources_item` AS item 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_item_categories` AS item_cat 
ON item.item_id = item_cat.item_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_category` AS category 
ON item_cat.category_id = category.category_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_fieldval` AS fieldval 
ON item.item_id = fieldval.item_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_fielddef` AS fielddef 
ON fieldval.fielddef_id = fielddef.fielddef_id
WHERE item.active=1 
AND (fielddef.fielddef_id="4" AND fieldval.value IN ("Documents tÃ©lÃ©chargeables")) 
AND (fielddef.fielddef_id="5" AND fieldval.value IN ("Anglais"))
```

---

This is a simplified example to let you know what i want to do... Please note that i can't change the database conception

```
TABLE ITEMS Store the ID and Title of an item.
id= INT / Primary / auto_increment
title = VARCHAR (255)
```

Each items has many custom fields (example: "color =red", "Country = France", etc..)

```
TABLE CUSTOM_FIELDNAME Stores the fieldname (definition => example : "Color", "Country")
fielddef_id = INT / PRIMARY / auto_increment
name = VARCHAR(255) (=> ex: Color, Country...)

TABLE CUSTOM_FIELDVALUE stores the field value (example : "red", "France")
item_id => foreign_key to link to the ITEMS TABLE
fielddef_id => foreign_key to link to the CUSTOM_FIELDNAME TABLE
value = VARCHAR(255) (=> ex: red, France...)
```

I need to list only items WHERE color = red AND Country = FRANCE

Sample datas:

```
TABLE ITEMS :
id=1 | Title = "first Item"
id=2 | Title = "A red French Item"

TABLE CUSTOM_FIELDNAME
fielddef_id = 1 | name = "Color"
fielddef_id = 2 | name = "Country"

TABLE CUSTOM_FIELDVALUE
item_id = 1 | fielddef_id = 1 | value = "Blue"
item_id = 1 | fielddef_id = 2 | value = "Germany"
item_id = 2 | fielddef_id = 1 | value = "Red"
item_id = 2 | fielddef_id = 2 | value = "France"
```

So my query looks like this :

```
SELECT items.title AS title
custom_fieldname.name as customName
custom_fieldvalue.value as customValue
FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN `custom_fieldvalue`
ON items.id = custom_fieldvalue.item_id 
LEFT JOIN `custom_fieldname`
ON custom_fieldvalue.fielddef_id = custom_fieldname.fielddef_id 
WHERE(custom_fieldname.fielddef_id="1" AND custom_fieldvalue.value "Red") AND (custom_fieldname.fielddef_id="2" AND custom_fieldvalue.value "France")
```

Comment: Pls provide some sample data and expected output based on the sample data. Currently your question is not clear to me. If I had to guess, you are looking for group_concat().

Comment: Taking on board Sagi's point about putting LEFT JOIN conditions in the ON clause, one option is to LEFT JOIN the fielddef and fiedval tables twice, once for each condition. Another option, which is slower, but easier to read is to the classic `MAX(CASE WHEN...)` syntax of a typical pivot query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT i.item_id AS id
     , item.title AS title
     , item.active AS active
     , item_cat.category_id AS cat_id
     , item_cat.item_id AS item_id
     , category.category_id
     , category.category_name as cat_name
     , category.category_alias as cat_alias 
     , v4.value v4_value
     , d4.fielddef_id d4_fielddef_id
     , v5.value v5_value
     , d5.fielddef_id d5_fielddef_id
  FROM cms_module_listit2ressources_item i
  LEFT 
  JOIN cms_module_listit2ressources_item_categories ic
    ON ic.item_id = i.item_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cms_module_listit2ressources_category c
    ON c.category_id = ic.category_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cms_module_listit2ressources_fieldval v4
    ON v4.item_id = i.item_id 
   AND v4.value IN ("Documents téléchargeables") 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cms_module_listit2ressources_fielddef d4
    ON d4.fielddef_id = v4.fielddef_id
   AND d4.fielddef_id = 4 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cms_module_listit2ressources_fieldval v5
    ON v5.item_id = i.item_id
   AND v5.value IN ("Anglais")
  LEFT 
  JOIN cms_module_listit2ressources_fielddef d5
    ON d5.fielddef_id = v5.fielddef_id 
   AND d5.fielddef_id = 5 
 WHERE i.active = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I've only replaced LEFT JOIN by INNER JOIN to only match when both conditions are completed!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **DON'T** put the conditions on the right table of a `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause, they should only be placed in the `ON()` clause.

Secondly, your last condition doesn't make sense and will always be `FALSE` , a field can't be equal to more then 1 value at a time.

Thirdly, string comparison should be done with a single quote `'` and not double `"` .

And lastly, you should use `CONCAT()` , try something like this(I assume you'll have to adjust it a little bit) :

```
SELECT CONCAT(First_Field,'=>',Second_Field)
FROM `cms_module_listit2ressources_item` AS item 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_item_categories` AS item_cat 
ON item.item_id = item_cat.item_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_category` AS category 
ON item_cat.category_id = category.category_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_fieldval` AS fieldval 
ON item.item_id = fieldval.item_id 
LEFT JOIN `cms_module_listit2ressources_fielddef` AS fielddef 
ON fieldval.fielddef_id = fielddef.fielddef_id     AND
  (fielddef.fielddef_id,fieldval.value) IN(('4','Documents  tÃ©lÃ©chargeables),
                                             ('5','Anglais'))
WHERE item.active=1
```

Comment: You should never use CONCAT. Not for anything. ever.

Comment: Usually when you say something like this, you should explain why.

Comment: Because CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT undermine the atomicity of SQL data. There's (almost) nothing that you can do with those functions that can't be done more effectively in application level code.

Comment: OK, so offer that to the OP, he didn't even provide any info about his application level. So I gave him a solution for MySQL - Which is exactly what he asked for.